# What's the difference between "diary" and "journal"?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between *diary* and *journal*? They seem like they could mean the same thing, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: A _diary_ is almost always written from a personal perspective. The word _journal_ has other meanings, but one of its definitions is a synonym for diary.  But this is basic dictionary stuff...

Comment: They're largely synonymous, though diary sometimes implies something more personal and/or private.

Comment: There are two major types of "journal".  One is a chronological account of events, and the other is a technical "periodical" magazine (which is technically chronological by issue, but the chronology is usually much less important).  Within the first (ie, chronological) category, "journal" may span the range from a personal diary to a formal bookkeeping document to a computer file used to keep a record of a computer's actions.  "Diary" is almost always a personal record of events and thoughts in largely chronological order.

Answer (score 18):

Diary and Journal are synonyms, but there is an important difference:

A diary is strictly a record of personal and daily experiences.
Journal could mean a more general record or logbook but more importantly a technical journal, that is a scientific or industry-related publication/periodical.

http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=journal

Summary:
Diary and Journal have the same specific meaning, but journal can have other meanings also.

Comment: Could we call a journal a collection of events, learnings, and reflections on specific topics (The Lancet, for example, is a medical journal), and a diary is a specific kind of journal where the subject is yourself?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where I heard this (and I even searched google for the source), but I hear people saying, "Girls keep diaries, boys keep journals."
I think they both mean the same thing, but you normally wouldn't hear a boy say, "I'm going to write in my diary."  They're more likely to say, "I keep a journal."

Comment: ...Reminds me of [this cartoon](http://www.cartoonstock.com/lowres/epa1586l.jpg)

Comment: I remember reading this in the Henry Reed (children's) series by Keith Robertson. A diary is more of a day-to-day writing, a journal is more topical.

Comment: @J.R. : "Access Denied"

Comment: @TOOGAM –  ‌@‌J.R.'s cartoon, [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20060224045606/https://www.cartoonstock.com/lowres/epa1586l.jpg), is of a king sitting at a small desk on a rainy day, with a quill pen writing the words "Reigned all day".

Answer (score 5):

A diary is mainly used to write things you would like to remember - daily activities, how the day was spent, what was done, the daily routine and anything that needs to get done.
A personal journal is a record of significant experiences. It is much more personal than a diary. It contains feelings, emotions, problems, and self-assurances and can be used to evaluate one’s life. For a journal, one does not just record one's experiences but also thoughts, feelings and reflections. Diary writing is a daily activity but one can write in a journal whenever there is a desire to write about significant experiences.

Someone asked for sources:

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition

jour•nal noun

1 a newspaper or magazine that deals with a particular subject or profession 
a scientific/trade journal
e.g. 
the British Medical Journal

2 used in the title of some newspapers 
e.g. the Wall Street Journal

3 a written record of the things you do, see, etc. every day 
He kept a journal of his travels across Asia.

diary noun

1 a book with spaces for each day of the year in which you can write down things you have to do in the future 
e.g. 
a desk diary 
I'll make a note of our next meeting in my diary.

2 a book in which you can write down the experiences you have each day, your private thoughts, etc 
e.g.
Do you keep a diary (= write one regularly) ? 
The writer's letters and diaries are being published next year.

© Oxford University Press, 2010

Comment: I would like to see some source of that, because a _journal_ is often an official, publicly available, log of events, and as such much less likely to be personal. A _diary_ on the other hand is what you describe as a journal. Think of _Anne Frank's diary_.

Comment: To me, the source does not support your statement in the first paragraph, and almost contradicts it.

Answer (score 1):

I kept (summer) diaries and journals a teenager. One summer, I wrote "diary" about random events taking place every few days. A couple summers later, I wrote in journal form, "A Summer's Travels," covering only those portions of my summer that was spent traveling in Europe and Appalachia. The journal was more "topical."